# vercel deployment caching shows old version of site

Tags: javascript, caching, browser, vercel

The browser saves site cache and always show the old version of my site after I push on Vercel until I clear browser cache fully or CTRL+SHIFT+R on the page, what do I do, happens with all the clients.

I have tried everything I could find on the internet.

Comment: Use cache control headers to reduce the caching time. This isn't really a programming question, it's a server configuration setting.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.